# Run multiple python files at same time

Tags: python

I understand that we can use Python `multiprocessing` module and will import `Process` for this.

But what will be our Python code, suppose we want to execute 2 files like `a.py`, `b.py` at same time.

I was expecting a Python script to include the above and not running files from two command prompts.

Below is the framework:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(file):
    #your subprocess code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = ["path/to/file1.py","path/to/file2.py","path/to/file3.py"]
    for i in files:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker(i))
        p.start()
```

What will be subprocess code ?

Comment: Open two cmds/shells and run them

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might be interested to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Just open two command prompts(in windows) or terminals (in other OS'). Then run each of the files in one window.